Are questions asking for a real-world location used in a film/scene on topic?
I wanted to ask a question asking where in a particular scene of a movie is the real-world location, with a provided screenshot of the scene.  Is that a valid question for this site?

Sure. We've got over 100 questions, most of them well-received and answered, about film-location

For questions relating to the location of filming, rather than the
location depicted in the final show. Use for questions trying to
determine where a film was shot.

